# Assign USB drive the letter "A:" in windows XP mode (on windows 7)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, disk-management

Is it possible to assign the drive letter "A:" to a USB pendrive?

I've tried it using the SUBST-command, mapping a network drive and via the diskmanagement console. But none of them seem to accept A: .

Are there any 3rd party programs that might do this instead?

Comment: I can do this in the disk management console just fine. Are you sure that you don't have a floppy drive (real, or imagined by Windows) clogging drive letter A? If try to find it in the device manager and disable it.

Comment: Gosh... nevermind I didn't read the device manager part :( That does the trick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to assign any drive letter to the USB drive using the disk manager in the computer management console. The only reason that you may not be able to, is because a drive letter is already occupied by another device. One way to solve this, if the drive doesn't appear in the disk manager, is to find the offending device (such as a floppy drive in this case) in the **device** manager and right click and disable it there.